# Web deployment failing on IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm trying to get Web Deploy setup on an IIS 8.5 server running on Server 2012 R2.

When attempting to deploy from Visual Studio I get the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer
>   ("foo"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web
>   Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management
>   Service") is started.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

I have installed Web Deploy 3.5 and 3.6 from the Web Platform Installer on the remote server and ensured that the Web Management Service is running.

[image]

I have also turned the firewall of on the remote server to make sure that it's not being blocked there.

`netstat -aon` yields the following relevant lines:

`TCP    [::]:8172              [::]:0                     LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8172           0.0.0.0:0                   LISTENING
TCP    <SERVER_IP>:8172      <MY_WORKSTATION_IP>:54055    TIME_WAIT
TCP    <SERVER_IP>:8172      <MY_WORKSTATION_IP>:54057    TIME_WAIT
TCP    <SERVER_IP>:8172      <MY_WORKSTATION_IP>:54059    TIME_WAIT
TCP    <SERVER_IP>:8172      <MY_WORKSTATION_IP>:54061    TIME_WAIT`

I can connect on port 8172 via telnet, but no matter what I do I can't get Web Deploy to work.